# Populate variable from required keys

Tags: php

`$data` variable get populated from required keys via `$personalDetailsRequiredFields`. The code below does work but is there a better shorter way?

```
   $personalDetailsRequiredFields = [
        'contact_title',
        'contact_first_name',
        'contact_last_name',
        'contact_phone_number',
        'contact_mobile_number',
        'contact_email',
    ];
    $personalDetails = SessionOrder::getPersonalDetails();

    foreach($personalDetails as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key,$personalDetailsRequiredFields)) {
            $data['personalDetails'][$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: always beating me to it mark

Comment: @MarkBaker Perfect! Never knew about 'array_intersect_key' - Feel free to post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data['personalDetails'] = array_intersect_key(
    $personalDetails, 
    array_flip($personalDetailsRequiredFields)
);
```

should give you what you want without needing the loop and if test